# oracle nhibernate connection

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, connection

I am trying to connect oracle 10g database through n hibernate,
can anyone help me the preliminary steps to be done to establish the connection,
I've connected sq l server 2000 easily and its working fine, now i try to connect oracle
but i am getting error "cannot open connection". please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Venkatesh D.

Answer (score 0):

For connection to the Oracle I have used [Oracle data provider](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html). And about configuration you can try to have a look [here](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/using-oracle-odp-with-nhibernate-from-a-c-class-library/) it helped to me.